# How to maintain cookies during redirects using perl's LWP::UserAgent?

Tags: perl, redirect, cookies, lwp, lwp-useragent

The HTTP Request I used to send to a specific website is now getting redirected which eventually broke my code. I realized that the cookies are not working anymore for the redirected domain (of course). I read the docs of LWP but I did not find any related option to preserve/maintain cookies automatically. Is there an easy way to do it?

*Just for a side note: this behavior works out of the box using Python's Requests class.*

Comment: make life easier on yourself, WWW::Mechanize is a subclass of LWP::UserAgent, and takes care of all the low level stuff for you, letting you just 'browse'

Comment: While WWW::Mechanize is nice, it might be overkill because it way heavier than LWP::UserAgent. It really depends on the use-case.

Comment: How does it look if you do it in your browser? I suggest you inspect the headers of all the requests and responses from the initial one through the redirect until the final page, and take a close look at the cookies. Without seeing that, it's going to be hard to help here I believe. The solution might be as simple as reaching into the cookie jar and slightly altering the cookie's domain.

Comment: If I manually set the cookies for the redirected domain as well, my code works as usual. However the redirected domain seems to be a random cdn server which is changing all the time. As you said I need to alter the cookie's domain through each redirect.
I agree on WWW::Mechanize being overkill for my issue.

Comment: See http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=35085

Comment: LWP  (and any browser) should check the cookies for the original domain and add them as headers to the HTTP message. After that the message may be redirected as required and the headers won't be changed. If you're seeing behaviour different from that then you have a bug, but we need far more detail to be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

The following adds support for cookies to LWP::UserAgent.

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( cookie_jar => {} );
```

It causes cookies returned in a response to be sent with subsequent matching requests, just like a browser does.

Comment: @papaiatis, Why not?